# Input stream ends within an object

Tags: input, stream, lisp, common-lisp

I want to count the number of rows in a flat file, and so I wrote the code:

```
(defun ff-rows (dir file)
  (with-open-file (str (make-pathname :name file
                                      :directory dir)
                                      :direction :input)
    (let ((rownum 0))
      (do ((line (read-line str file nil 'eof)
                 (read-line str file nil 'eof)))
          ((eql line 'eof) rownum)
        (incf rownum )))))
```

However I get the error:

```
*** - READ: input stream
       #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"/home/lambda/Documents/flatfile"
         @4>
      ends within an object
```

May I ask what the problem is here? I tried counting the rows; this operation is fine.

Note: Here is contents of the flat file that I used to test the function:

```
2 3 4 6 2 
1 2 3 1 2
2 3 4 1 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit shorter.

```
(defun ff-rows (dir file)
  (with-open-file (stream (make-pathname :name file
                                         :directory dir)
                          :direction :input)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil nil)
          while line count line)))
```

Note that you need to get the arguments for `READ-LINE` right. First is the stream. A file is not part of the parameter list.

Also generally is not a good idea to mix pathname handling into general Lisp functions.

```
(defun ff-rows (pathname)
  (with-open-file (stream pathname :direction :input)
    (loop for line = (read-line stream nil nil)
          while line count line)))
```

Do the pathname handling in another function or some other code. Passing pathname components to functions is usually a wrong design. Pass complete pathnames.

Using a LispWorks file selector:

```
CL-USER 2 > (ff-rows (capi:prompt-for-file "some file"))
27955
```

Even better is when all the basic I/O functions work on streams, and not pathnames. Thus you you could count lines in a network stream, a serial line or some other stream.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll be careful to handle pathnames separately.

Comment: It seems cleaner to pass the file and directory into `ff-rows`, since that is what a user would naturally pass into such a function, but I can see how that's the wrong design. If I ask the user to create a pathname that seems like the wrong design also. So then I could define a function that creates a pathname and executes `ff-rows`, but then I'm back to handling pathname components in another function.

Answer (score 4):

The problem, as far as I can tell, is the "file" in your (read-line ... ) call.

Based on the [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm), the signature of read-line is:

```
read-line &optional input-stream eof-error-p eof-value recursive-p
=> line, missing-newline-p
```

...which means that "file" is interpreted as eof-error-p, nil as eof-value and 'eof as recursive-p. Needless to say, problems ensue. If you remove "file" from the read-line call (e.g. `(read-line str nil :eof)`), the code runs fine without further modifications on my machine (AllegroCL & LispWorks.)

Comment: Thanks, I believe I was typing that in the wrong place- I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun ff-rows (dir file)
  (with-open-file
      (str (make-pathname :name file :directory dir)
           :direction :input)
    (let ((result 0))
      (handler-case
          (loop (progn (incf result) (read-line str)))
        (end-of-file () (1- result))
        (error () result)))))
```

Now, of course if you were more pedantic then I am, you could've specified what kind of error you want to handle exactly, but for the simple example this will do.

EDIT: I think @Moritz answered the question better, still this may be an example of how to use the error thrown by `read-line` to your advantage instead of trying to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll especially look into the `handler-case` and `end-of-file` functions.

Comment: I don't think condition handling is a very good idea in this case.